# Make CSS grid cell Image items use all available space

Tags: html, css, css-tables, css-grid

I am making a CSS grid of images with captions and I want the images to display as large as possible, with the captions taking up as little space as possible.

I want the caption row to be narrow and the image row to be deep, not all rows being the same size as is happening with my code.

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| caption | caption | caption | caption |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  image  |  image  |  image  |  image  |
|  image  |  image  |  image  |  image  |
|  image  |  image  |  image  |  image  |
|  image  |  image  |  image  |  image  |
|  image  |  image  |  image  |  image  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

My solution shows the rows for the captions and the rows for the images at the same height, rather than making the row for the images as large as possible and using object-fit to prevent the aspect ratio of the image from being compromised.

I have put the code in a codepen https://codepen.io/charlbury/pen/RedWWB?editors=1100

CSS:

```
.WHR-visualiser {
  display: flex;
  width: 660px;
  height: 328PX;
}

.left {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.caption {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  text-align: center;
}

.left>div img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Header:</h1>
<div class="WHR-visualiser">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate with a longer name than the others</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>

    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/a98f6e81-2327-4e2f-94b6-63bc90494884.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/ea5762e7-b1a3-416d-89a6-16f934d44867.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/a112a543-9917-400a-a021-f9430e2d594a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/5a368d6d-2df6-40b7-b1fc-5a5725bef99a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/05c160f9-06b3-4f6b-bbff-6aad7ff923b0.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/dbd0fb84-b4ff-4404-be39-cf7aa6329916.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>

    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/dbd0fb84-b4ff-4404-be39-cf7aa6329916.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/05c160f9-06b3-4f6b-bbff-6aad7ff923b0.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/5a368d6d-2df6-40b7-b1fc-5a5725bef99a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/a112a543-9917-400a-a021-f9430e2d594a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/ea5762e7-b1a3-416d-89a6-16f934d44867.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/a98f6e81-2327-4e2f-94b6-63bc90494884.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>

    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/a98f6e81-2327-4e2f-94b6-63bc90494884.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/a98f6e81-2327-4e2f-94b6-63bc90494884.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/a98f6e81-2327-4e2f-94b6-63bc90494884.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/a98f6e81-2327-4e2f-94b6-63bc90494884.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/05c160f9-06b3-4f6b-bbff-6aad7ff923b0.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/05c160f9-06b3-4f6b-bbff-6aad7ff923b0.jpg" />
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<h1>Footer:</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add image width 100% to all image same to be same size

```css
.WHR-visualiser {
  display: flex;
  width: 660px;
  height: 328PX;
}

.left {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.caption {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  text-align: center;
}

.left>div img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width:100% ;
}
```

```html
<h1>Header:</h1>
<div class="WHR-visualiser">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate with a longer name than the others</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>

    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/a98f6e81-2327-4e2f-94b6-63bc90494884.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/ea5762e7-b1a3-416d-89a6-16f934d44867.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/a112a543-9917-400a-a021-f9430e2d594a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/5a368d6d-2df6-40b7-b1fc-5a5725bef99a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/05c160f9-06b3-4f6b-bbff-6aad7ff923b0.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/dbd0fb84-b4ff-4404-be39-cf7aa6329916.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>

    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/dbd0fb84-b4ff-4404-be39-cf7aa6329916.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/05c160f9-06b3-4f6b-bbff-6aad7ff923b0.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/5a368d6d-2df6-40b7-b1fc-5a5725bef99a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/a112a543-9917-400a-a021-f9430e2d594a.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/ea5762e7-b1a3-416d-89a6-16f934d44867.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/a98f6e81-2327-4e2f-94b6-63bc90494884.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>
    <div class="caption">1. Brandenburg Gate</div>

    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/a98f6e81-2327-4e2f-94b6-63bc90494884.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/a98f6e81-2327-4e2f-94b6-63bc90494884.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/a98f6e81-2327-4e2f-94b6-63bc90494884.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/a98f6e81-2327-4e2f-94b6-63bc90494884.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/05c160f9-06b3-4f6b-bbff-6aad7ff923b0.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/aigaming/WhereIsWhere/Games/8e962ec7-5fb9-404a-b393-0a138cd78aab/05c160f9-06b3-4f6b-bbff-6aad7ff923b0.jpg" />
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<h1>Footer:</h1>
```

Comment: This makes the images fill the available width, but does not make them fill the available height. How can I also make them fill the available height?